# Spring Boot: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0

Tags: gradle

I am facing an issue when running ./gradlew compileJava to make Qentity in the build directory.

The error was:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

Following is my code:

```
plugins {
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.learning'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    //queryDSL
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.4.0:jakarta'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${dependencyManagement.importedProperties['querydsl.version']}:jakarta"
    //annotationProcessor "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api"



    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"

querydsl{
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir
}
sourceSets{
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}
configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}
compileQuerydsl{
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

I tried to find a solution through websites but they said the solution in basis on gradle 6.0

Answer (score 0):

This error should be a warning, the possible fix should be:

Edit in your gradle.settings to fix this issue in your project by changing

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}
```

to

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

If there are further warnings run `./gradlew --warning-mode=all` in your terminal and post the output as an edit to your question.